# AWS cli: not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have an AWS account in which I am assuming a role named A(`role-A`), from that role I have created another role named B(`role-B`) through the web console and attached the administrator policy to that role

Here is cli configuration

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <>
aws_secret_access_key = <>
region = eu-central-1

[role-B]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<id>:role/ics-role
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::<id>:mfa/<name>
external_id = <name>
source_profile = default
```

`role-B` which I have created from `role-A`

When i try to get the  role details

```
aws --profile role-B sts get-caller-identity
```

I am getting the following error

*An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<>:user/<> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/ics-role*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to check the trust relationship policy document of the iam role to confirm that your user is in it.

Additionally make sure that the iam user has explicit permissions allowing them to assume that role.

The trust relationship should look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/person"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I didn't get any permission issues while creating the roles and policy attachment.
What do you mean by trust document

Comment: In the console it'll be the trust relationship, I'll update the answer to include an example.

Comment: This helped me solve my issue because on opening the trust relationship tab I discovered there was an external ID being set.

Comment: For any followers: NB that this is on the Role itself, not the Policy or the User

Answer (score 2):

My issue was I had a condition set in the policy json.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000:dave"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Condition": {
           // Condition set here
        }
    }]
}
```

I removed the condition and it works now no issues.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000:dave"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }]
}
```